# Finding values in the database

Tags: python, telegram-bot, mysql-python

How can I find a value in a database by two parameters:

```py
info = db.execute (
    f "SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status =?, Type =?", [status, Type]
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use some sort of ORM like [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) or [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for interacting with databases in your program because it makes interaction with databases a lot easier.

And for answering to your question, i think you try something like below :

```py
f "SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status ='{status}', Type ='{Type}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info = db.execute (
    f "SELECT * FROM 'storage_users' WHERE status = ? AND Type =?", [status, Type]
)
```

The boolean operator is used to join two conditions that are required in the database query.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.